# LINQ Nested Grouping - I don't understand the MSDN example

Tags: c#, linq

As stated in the title, I cannot comprehend how the query in the below link works.

[MSDN - LINQ Nested Grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb545974.aspx)

Here is the query itself:

```
var queryNestedGroups =
    from student in students
    group student by student.Year into newGroup1
    from newGroup2 in
        (from student in newGroup1
         group student by student.LastName)
    group newGroup2 by newGroup1.Key;
```

I think the best approach would be me explaining what I understand and don't understand from this and maybe someone can lead me in the right direction.

OK, so my idea is:

- we create a couple of groups that contain objects of type *student*,
- [the inside of parenthesis] we take each of those groups and group the students inside them to create new groups,

(At this point we have *x* outer groups, each of them contain *y* inner groups.)

- [here let's just focus on one outer group] we take each *newGroup2* from *newGroup1* and group it by *newGroup1*'s key.

But *newGroup1* already has only students of one year, so *newGroup2* also has only students of one year. Why do we need to group this again?

Comment: Perhaps you should do an experiment. When you replace the final `group` with a `select`, how do the results differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to understand when presented in method syntax query:

```
var query = students.GroupBy(student => student.Year)
                    .SelectMany(
                        newGroup1 => newGroup1.GroupBy(student => student.LastName),
                        (newGroup1, newGroup2) => new { newGroup1, newGroup2 } )
                    .GroupBy(x => x.newGroup1.Key, x => x.newGroup2);
```

As you can see, `from` after `group by` is transformed into `SelectMany` so after that you have one big collection of anonymous type with two properties: `newGroup1` and `newGroup2`. That's why you have to group is again using `newGroup1.Key`.

Comment: I'm almost there. What I would like to know now is if these anonymous types have the same members as type `student`, but with additional properties?